# Quick way to determine if a piecewise-defined function is injective/surjective.

Tags: functions

Let $f(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map determined by:

$f(x)=\begin{cases} x &x \ge 2\\
 \frac{x^3}{4} &-1\le x < 2\\
 x &x < -1\end{cases}$

Is there an easy way to determine if this function is injective and surjective?

Injectivity means that $f(x) = f(y)$, hence for both $x>2$ and $x< -1$, $x = y$. Is the same true for $x^3\over4$?

As for surjectivity, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Draw its graph.You can easily see that this function is continuous and strictly increasing. Moreover, it is unbounded above and below. Hence, it is both injective and surjective

Comment: I have graphed the function in desmos.com and I can see both of these properties of the function. However, what I am more interested in is a quick method to test for both injectivity and surjectivity for these types of functions, where the function changes depending on x, as above: $x$ if $x>2$, ${x^3}\over 4$ if $-1 \le$ ... etc

Comment: You say that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  However, you have not defined $f(2)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I saw that as well, however, this is a question from a previous examination paper. I didn't write it. But when $x=2, {x^3\over 4} = 2$, so it doesn't really matter if its $x, x \ge 2$ or ${{x^3}\over4}, -1\le x\le2$. Let's just assume that $x, x \ge 2$ for simplicity, and I will edit the question to include that.

Answer (score 2):

**injectivity:**  If $x \geq 2$, then $f(x) = x \geq 2$.  Moreover, if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $f(x_1) = x_1 = x_2 = f(x_2)$.

If $x < - 1$, then $f(x) = x < -1$.  Moreover, if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $f(x_1) = x_1 = x_2 = f(x_2)$.

It remains to establish that if $-1 \leq x < 2$, then $-1 \leq x < 2$ and that, if this is the case,  then $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.

We will show that $f$ is strictly increasing on this interval.  Suppose $x_1, x_2 \in [-1, 2)$ and $x_1 > x_2$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
f(x_1) - f(x_2) & = \frac{x_1^3}{4} - \frac{x_2^3}{4}\\
                & = \frac{1}{4}(x_1^3 - x_2^3)\\
                & = \frac{1}{4}(x_1 - x_2)(x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2)\\
                & = \frac{1}{4}(x_1 - x_2)\left(x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + \frac{1}{4}x_2^2 + \frac{3}{4}x_2^2\right)\\
                & = \frac{1}{4}(x_1 - x_2)\left[\left(x_1 + \frac{x_2}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}x_2^2\right]\\
                & > 0
\end{align*}
Thus, $f$ is strictly increasing on $[-1, 2)$.  Moreover, if $x \in [-1, 2)$, then 
$$f(-1) = \frac{(-1)^3}{4} = -\frac{1}{4} \leq x < \frac{2^3}{4} = 2$$
so, if $x \in [-1, 2)$, then $-1 < f(x) < 2$.

Consequently, $f$ is injective.

**surjectivity:** Since $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, for the function to be surjective, we require that every real number be in the range.  We have shown that 
\begin{align*}
x \geq 2 & \implies f(x) \geq 2\\
-1 \leq x < 2 & \implies -\frac{1}{4} \leq x < 2\\
x < -1 & \implies f(x) < -1
\end{align*}
Thus, $f(x) \notin [-1, -1/4)$.  Hence, $f$ is not surjective.

[image: graph_of_piecewise_function]

The results above can be obtained more easily by sketching the function's graph.  Since a horizontal line crosses the graph at most once, the function is injective.  Since the horizontal line $y = -1/2$ does not cross the graph, the function is not surjective.